# How to get canvas parameters in Salesforce to Salesforce integration

Tags: integration, canvas

I am new to integration and trying a salesforce to salesforce integration using canvas. I am facing a problem while retrieving canvas parameters in visual force page. Not sure what I am doing wrong.
Following is the code added on visual force page to retrieve parameter:

```
<script>
Sfdc.canvas(function() {
var sr = JSON.parse('<%=signedRequestJson%>');
Sfdc.canvas.byId('username').innerHTML = sr.context.environment.parameters.contactId ;

});
</script> <br>
```

Please help.

Comment: What does you JSON look like? Are you splitting it out from the signed request and base 64 decoding it first?